# Node 14 exception issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, hadoop-yarn

I have website on `React`. It runs on `Windows Server 2019 (IIS 10)` and uses `Node v14.21.3`, `Yarn 1.22.19`. I call `npm start` command to run it using `Command Prompt`. The problem is that sometimes it just crashes with the following issue:

```
internal/child_process.js:497
      throw errnoException(err, 'kill');
      ^
Error: kill ENOSYS
    at ChildProcess.kill (internal/child_process.js:497:13)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\app\insurance_site\node_modules\cross-env\dist\index.js:53:19)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28) {
  errno: -4054,
  code: 'ENOSYS',
  syscall: 'kill'
}

internal/process/per_thread.js:210
      throw errnoException(err, 'kill');
      ^
Error: kill ENOSYS
    at process.kill (internal/process/per_thread.js:210:13)
    at process.listener (C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\lib\cli.js:76410:15)
    at process.emit (events.js:400:28) {
  errno: -4054,
  code: 'ENOSYS',
  syscall: 'kill'
}
```

It's an old project and uses some outdated components. You can check out what components are used in this project below:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "web-site",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@kunukn/react-collapse": "^2.2.7",
    "@rehooks/window-scroll-position": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/dotenv": "=6.1.1",
    "@types/express": "=4.17.1",
    "@types/js-base64": "=2.3.1",
    "@types/lodash": "=4.14.149",
    "@types/morgan": "=1.7.37",
    "@types/node": "10.17.17",
    "@types/node-fetch": "=2.5.0",
    "@types/node-sass": "=4.11.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.16",
    "@types/react-autosuggest": "^9.3.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.5",
    "@types/react-fontawesome": "=1.6.1",
    "@types/react-helmet": "=5.0.3",
    "@types/react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.5",
    "@types/react-router-config": "=5.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/react-select": "=3.0.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.6",
    "@types/whatwg-fetch": "^0.0.33",
    "app-root-path": "^2.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.12.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "customize-cra": "^0.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "fetch-everywhere": "^1.0.5",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "js-base64": "^2.4.3",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2",
    "odata-query": "6.0.0-1",
    "rc-steps": "^3.5.0",
    "re-reselect": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-app-rewire-less": "^2.1.3",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.3",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dropdown-date": "^2.2.7",
    "react-ga": "^2.6.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^3.28.2",
    "react-hotjar": "^2.0.2",
    "react-id-generator": "^3.0.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-lines-ellipsis": "^0.14.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.1",
    "react-modern-calendar-datepicker": "^3.1.6",
    "react-owl-carousel2": "^0.3.0",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "react-router-config": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "2.13.0",
    "react-select": "=3.0.8",
    "react-spinners": "=0.7.1",
    "redux": "=4.0.4",
    "redux-actions": "=2.6.5",
    "redux-thunk": "=2.3.0",
    "reselect": "=4.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "=2.4.5",
    "ts-loader": "=6.0.4",
    "ts-node": "=8.3.0",
    "use-media": "=1.4.0",
    "use-react-router": "=1.0.7",
    "uuid": "=3.3.3",
    "webpack-cli": "=3.3.8",
    "webpack-node-externals": "=1.7.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "=3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "yarn run build",
    "start": "yarn start:server",
    "start:dev": "yarn run build && yarn start:server:dev",
    "start:server": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production ts-node build_server/server.js",
    "start:server:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node build_server/server.js",
    "start:client": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build:server": "ts-node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.server.config.js",
    "build:client": "react-app-rewired build",
    "build": "yarn run build:client && yarn run build:server",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "=3.5.1",
    "style-loader": "=1.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Any ideas how to find/debug what causes such issue? Thank you.

Comment: Check if the server has standard C library installed. The error code `ENOSYS` can be checked [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html#index-ENOSYS) and the `kill` system call can be checked [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html#:~:text=The%20kill()%20system%20call,group%20of%20the%20calling%20process.).

Comment: @0xts

What is the name of this C library on `Windows Server 2019`? I have installed `Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 - 2022` redistributable package. Where I can check if this C library is installed or not on the server? Thanks.

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention that you were talking about Windows server. In short, as per your stack trace, the errors are caused by `yarn` & `cross-env`, for calling `process.kill` with an invalid signal. To elaborate, process based multi-tasking is not supported by Windows, but only Unix based OS'es. Though NodeJs internally has an implementation such that node's `process.kill` uses windows API for termination, it doesn't support all [signals](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html). `SIGHUP` for instance. The libraries could be using an unsupported signal.

Comment: @0xts

So, how to fix this issue? What do you recommend to do in such case (update `Yarn/Node`)? Thanks.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue and see when exactly it happens, once determined, look into the libraries source that's causing the issue, do some reasearch, and if it seems like an issue with library implementation, open a issue on GitHub.